# How to get URL to source code from jira issue using java?

Tags: java, jira, atlassian-fisheye

There is an Activity Module in Jira issues. It contains Source tab which can link to e.g. FishEye. Does it exist any possible way to achieve that URL to FishEye using Java?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to do. Is this question similar to your problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314197/how-can-i-programatically-get-source-code-information-from-issue-number-in-jira

Comment: I saw it earlier. It is about EQL, not Java.

Comment: Please clarify what 'that URL' is and where your Java code should be running (a standalone app, a JIRA plugin...)?